# How do I Download A Legacy ( Older ) Version of FDT 5.0 or FDT 4.5?

Tags: fdt, legacy-app

I'm looking for older versions for FDT to download. Where can I find them?
I rely on a particular workflow that existed in one of these earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

Legacy versions of FDT can be found via the FAQ on FDT's website:

[How do I Download FDT 5.6? (Standalone)](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FAQ#How_do_I_Download_FDT_5.5.3F_.28Standalone.29)

[How do I Download FDT 5.0? (Standalone)](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FAQ#How_do_I_Download_FDT_5.3F_.28Standalone.29)

[How do I Download FDT 4? (Standalone)](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FAQ#How_do_I_Download_FDT_4.3F_.28Standalone.29)

Versions of FDT 4 & 5 include:

- Windows 32 Bit
- Windows 64 Bit
- OSX 32 Bit
- OSX 64 Bit
- Linux 32 Bit
- Linux 64 Bit

FDT 3.5 (Galileo based, Ganymede compatible)

[FDT 3.5 Windows 32 Bit](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/update/installer/FDTEnterpriseWindows.exe)

[FDT 3.5 Mac Cocoa 32 Bit](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/update/installer/FDTEnterpriseMacCarbon.zip)